# A code for palindrome(errors given below)

Tags: java

```
package palindrome;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Palindrome 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the word = > ");
        String word = input.nextLine();
        int flag = 0;
        int x = word.length();
        int i = 0;
        int j = x;
        for(; i<=x/2 && j>=x/2; i++,j--)
        {
            if(word.charAt(i)!=word.charAt(j))
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            System.out.printf("The word '%s' is a palindrome", word);
        }
        else 
            System.out.printf("The word '%s' is not a palindrome", word);
    }


}
```

## Output scream error:

Enter the word = > madam

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
at palindrome.Palindrome.main(Palindrome.java:16)
```

Comment: Output scream! A noisy sequence of bytes?

Comment: I am tempted to mark this a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it, but that's not specific to `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`...

Comment: If your string has `x` characters, then the index of last character is `x - 1`, not `x`.

Comment: `int flag = 0;` It would be more conventional to make this a `boolean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set j's initial value to length-1

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Scratch 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the word = > ");
        String word = input.nextLine();
        int flag = 0;
        int x = word.length()-1;
        int i = 0;
        int j = x;
        for(; i<=x/2 && j>=x/2; i++,j--)
        {
            if(word.charAt(i)!=word.charAt(j))
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }

        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            System.out.printf("The word '%s' is a palindrome", word);
        }
        else 
            System.out.printf("The word '%s' is not a palindrome", word);
    }


}
```

Comment: It would be better to set `j`'s value to `x - 1`, rather than setting `x`'s value to `word.length()-1`. Then again, changing the loop guard to `i < j` would be easier, and would eliminate the need for `x`.

Comment: Given the code, one simple fixes with minimum change. I mean look at the code man, would you use that much variable for such a trivial task?

Answer (score 2):

```
int j = x;
```

should be:

```
int j = x-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Index is start from 0 in array.

```
package palindrome;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Palindrome
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the word = > ");
    String word = input.nextLine();
    int flag = 0;
    int x = word.length();
    int i = 0;
    int j = x-1;
    for(; i<=x/2 && j>=x/2; i++,j--)
    {
        System.out.println(i+" " +j );
        if(word.charAt(i)!=word.charAt(j))
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag==0)
    {
        System.out.printf("The word '%s' is a palindrome", word);
    }
    else
        System.out.printf("The word '%s' is not a palindrome", word);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you just forget to reduce the length of the word by 1:
remember index of Strings and Arrays in Java begins from 0 so the length should always be minus 1 since it will not be reached. example if the length of your words is 4 you can get up to index 3 that is 0 to 3 makes total length of 4.

```
int x = word.length()-1;
    int i = 0;
    int j = x;
    for (; i <= x / 2 && j >= x / 2; i++, j--) {
        if (word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(j)) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the other answers:
A string is an array of chars, so if you write "madam"

```
[m][a][d][a][m] -> is 5 letters, so its length is 5
[0][1][2][3][4] -> but the indexes start with 0, so the last one is 4
```

Hence, the `x=word.length()-1`

Answer (score 0):

I got the mistake in your code.

"value of j = x;" // is wrong 
As String is a character array it starts with 0 to string.length-1.

thus  **int j = x-1** ; // will do right

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you should have a seprate method to check for palindrome, This way you make your code clean and quality code.You can use below method to check for palindrome:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the word = > ");
        String word = input.nextLine();

       if(isPalindrome(word))
       {
           System.out.printf("The word '%s' is a palindrome", word);
       }
      else 
          System.out.printf("The word '%s' is not a palindrome", word);
}


private static boolean isPalindrome(String input) {
        if(input == null || input.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        for(int i=0,j=input.length() -1; i > j; i++,j-- ) {
            if(input.charAt(i) != input.charAt(j)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I suppose this happens because of the result of 5 divided to 2.
Try keeping the middle length first as integer.